# TFS - using features across iterations

Tags: tfs, alm

My team is using TFS 2013 and we've realized we haven't really been using the structure properly (e.g. iterations, features, pbis, etc).

To start "fresh" but still have easy access to all of our other work items and history etc. we figured we'll put everything that's been done so far into a "prototype iteration" and then create a new iteration and put new features, pbis, tasks, bugs in there.

We haven't finished a lot of the previously defined features, pbis, and tasks though so I thought I could maybe pull some of relevant work items out of the "prototype iteration" and set them to the new iteration then keep going.

I don't know if this is a good idea or not. Maybe there is a better way to handle the bad structure we were using. (any alternate suggestions would be greatly appreciated!)

If I continue with this method though, I end up with some strange things, like a Feature is assigned to the new iteration, though some of the PBIs and tasks for it are completed and in the old iteration. Should I just open a new feature instead? Or is this not really a problem? I'm worried about having strange links to other iterations or things showing up on the backlog that I wouldn't expect.

Answer (score 2):

If a PBI or Feature has to be listed on your team, but it is not part of your team then it will show up with a hollow work item type indicator rather than the solid one.

It's not a big deal to manage.

Note: You need to update to TFS 2015 for this. This is a free upgrade.

Comment: The hollowed-out color bar for work items not owned by the team is part of TFS2015

Comment: Correct, as TFS upgrade are free there is no good reason not to take advantage of the latest features.